# Can I make tox fail when there are TODOs in the code?

Tags: grep, tox

Currently, I run

```
grep -rnI "TODO" foodir
```

and `tox` to check if I can commit. Is there a way to make tox fail if the grep returns something?

Answer (score 1):

`exit 1` should be enough. Something like this in `tox.ini`:

```
[testenv]
commands =
    grep -FInrq TODO . && exit 1 || exit 0
```